# Is the role of "tempdb" in SQL Server similar to that of "swap" in MySQL and Linux?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, tempdb

do we have the "tempdb" concept in other database technologies or it is just in SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

While there are conceptual similarities between SQL Server's `tempdb` and the concept of swapping in MySQL, Linux, and other operating systems, they aren't directly analogous. Let's break this down:

1. **SQL Server's `tempdb`**:

   - It's a workspace for temporary objects like temporary tables, table variables, cursors, internal objects for work tables, row versioning, etc.
   - It holds intermediate results for operations like sorting and grouping.
   - It's also used for row versioning and snapshot isolation.
   - Data in `tempdb` is transient and is cleared upon server restart.
2. **MySQL's swap**:

   - When MySQL runs out of physical memory, it may start using swap space on the disk, essentially using it as "virtual memory".
   - Swapping can significantly degrade database performance because disk access is much slower than RAM access.
   - Swap space in the context of MySQL isn't a designated space for temporary objects, but rather an overflow area for when physical memory is exhausted.
3. **Linux's Swap**:

   - Swap space in Linux is used when the amount of physical memory (RAM) is full. If the system needs more memory resources and the RAM is full, inactive pages in memory are moved to the swap space.
   - Like with MySQL, swapping can degrade performance since disk operations are slower than in-memory operations.

In essence:

- `tempdb` in SQL Server is a database specifically designed for temporary operations and objects. Its design is intentional and is an integral part of SQL Server's operation.
- Swap space in MySQL or Linux is a mechanism to deal with memory exhaustion. While it ensures the system or database keeps running when out of RAM, it does so at the cost of performance.

It's more accurate to compare `tempdb` to MySQL's internal temporary tables or Oracle's temporary tablespaces, though each RDBMS has its own specifics in handling temporary workloads.

Comment: FWIW, `tempdb` in SQL Server is also where Memory overflow ends up during query processing.

Comment: And SQL Server's virtual memory can be "paged out" at the OS level.  The Windows Page File is similar to Linux's Swap.  You can prevent paging by granting SQL Server the "Lock Pages In Memory" OS privilege, in which case SQL Server will directly manage physical memory bypassing the Windows Virtual Memory manager.